# Create a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, controller, graphql

I am trying to create a controller and I am getting an error that the result cannot implicitly convert type bool to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult

```
try
{
    var result = await _ datasightClient.RemoveLicense(userId);
    return result;
}
catch (ClientException)
{
    return _internalServerErrorStatusCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 try
  {
  var result = await _ datasightClient.RemoveLicense(userId);
     return Ok(result);
     }
    catch (ClientException)
    {
  return BadRequest( _internalServerErrorStatusCode);
    }
```